# Replace Database value at the time of Gridview binding using c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am displaying some database value inside Gridview using c# and asp.net.I need to change the value by keeping some condition before bind inside Grid view.I am explaining my code below.

> HealthComment.aspx:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="comnt_Gridview" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="100%" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered margin-top-zero" OnSelectedIndexChanged="comnt_Gridview_OnSelectedIndexChanged"  onrowdeleting="comnt_Gridview_RowDeleting" DataKeyNames="Bnr_ID"  >
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sl. No" ItemStyle-CssClass="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
<ItemTemplate>
          <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
 /ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Health ID" ItemStyle-CssClass="col-md-1 col-sm-1" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="healthid" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Health_ID") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" ItemStyle-CssClass="col-md-1 col-sm-1" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
<ItemTemplate>
 <asp:Label ID="Url" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Health_Comment_Status") %>'></asp:Label>
 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>

 </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

> HealthComment.aspx.cs:

```
comnt_Gridview.DataSource = objhealthCommentBL.getHealthCommentDetails();
comnt_Gridview.DataBind();
```

> healthCommentBL.cs:

```
private healthCommentDL objhealthCommentDL = new healthCommentDL();
        public DataTable getHealthCommentDetails()
        {
            try
            {
                DataSet ds = objhealthCommentDL.getHealthCommentDetails();
                DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
                return dt;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }
```

> healthCommentDL.cs:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CmVar.convar);
        public DataSet getHealthCommentDetails()
        {
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                string sql = "SELECT Health_Comment_ID,Health_ID,Health_Comment_Status from T_Health_Comment";
                sql += " order by Bnr_ID ASC ";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
                SqlDataAdapter objadp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                objadp.Fill(ds);
                return ds;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
                con.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Here my requirement is there are two types of Health_Comment_Status in the database `i.e-R and A`.When status will be `R` the Gridview will display `Rejected` and when status is `A` the Gridview will display `Accepted`.Please help me to do this.Thanks.

Comment: Did you get a chance to look at my answer..?

Answer (score 0):

Read row value RowDataBound and put it on conditaion

Comment: @ Promod: Can you write your answer ?

Comment: This does not provide and answer to the question. Please update your previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < GridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    string Health_Comment_Status;
    Health_Comment_Status = GridView2.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text; // here you go vr =   the value of the cel
    if (Health_Comment_Status  == "R") // you can check for anything
    {
        GridView2.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text = "Rejected";
        // you can format this cell 
    }
    else
   { 
    GridView2.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text = "Accepted";
   }
}
```

You can set name and Item index as per  your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this using C# [Conditional Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) like this:-

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <asp:Label ID="Url" runat="server" 
  Text='<%#Eval("Health_Comment_Status") == "R" ? "Rejected" : "Accepted" %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```